# cypress binding to custom events

Tags: node.js, end-to-end, cypress

I need cypress to stub or spy some function after some custom event is fired (that is happening before window:onload) like jQuery.ready event

```
  cy.on('window:jQuery:ready', (win)=> {
    win.console.log("Jquery is ready")
  })
```

this being within individual test never being executed. Any help would be highly appreciated